# Using Lookup function to pull in specific contentblockby ID in an email with ampscript

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can I pull in a specific contentblockbyID using the lookup function in ampscript based on the conditional IF/ELSE statement?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a dynamic variable within your Lookup statement.  Here is an example. I have a table with my group names and their respective content block ids.  I can use an if statement to set the group name and then use that variable in my Lookup to return the value I needed.

In your email:

```html
%%[
  if @p_type=1 then
    set @CB_type = "A"
  else then
    set @CB_type = "B"
  endif

  set @CB_ID = Lookup("TABLENAME","CONTENTBLOCK_IDS","NAME",@CB_type)
]%%

%%=CONTENTBLOCKBYID(@CB_ID)=%%
```

DATA EXTENSION NAME: "TABLE NAME"
COLUMNS - NAME / CONTENTBLOCK_IDS
Row 1 - A / 123 
Row 2 - B / 124

Here are some great resources:

- [AMPSCRIPTGUIDE - IF Statements](https://ampscript.guide/statements/)
- [AMPSCRIPTGUIDE - LOOKUP Function](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/)
- [AMPSCRIPTGUIDE - CONTENTBLOCKBYID Function](https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyid/)